Horror movie late 70's or early 80's
I'm looking for a horror movie from the late 70s or early 80s. It was about a white blue eyed boy buried inside a house/castle, with a gold chain around his neck. He was killed by (probably) his own father.

What language and country is it from? This is very lacking in detail so anything else you can remember would be helpful.

I believe I have the answer.  The 1980 horror movie The Changeling matches the description in several important respects.  The movie involves a (castle-like) mansion haunted by the young boy Joseph who was murdered there by his own father and replaced with an impostor.  Joseph's birth medal (which is on a chain) is a very important plot element, as physical evidence that the impostor is not the actual Joseph.  I don't remember if Joseph was blue-eyed, or if his body was found in the house, but the rest matches.  Can the question be re-opened for answering?

@afeldspar - I've reopened so you can answer

I believe the movie you're looking for is The Changeling, a 1980 movie with George C. Scott and Trish Van Devere.
After his wife and child die in a tragic road accident, Scott's character John Russell moves into a Victorian-era mansion (which is large and elaborate and castle-like - matching one of the points of your description.)  
The mansion is also haunted by the ghost of Joseph, a young boy who was killed there decades ago by his father.  (I actually consider the "by (probably) his own father" a particularly strong point of identification - the murder scene is shown to the audience without much explanation, and we are left to guess/deduce who the murderer is and why he did it.  I myself didn't know why Richard killed his son and replaced him with an impostor until years later; I guess I missed it when they filled in that information later.)
Joseph's body is not buried in the mansion; it's discovered in the well on a separate property.  However, it's found along with Joseph's baptism medal (typically worn on a chain around the neck) and the baptism medal turns out to be significant physical evidence (the impostor has his own, but obviously, there shouldn't be two for the same child) and a plot driver (receiving the real Joseph's birth medal may be the cause for the impostor having an ultimately fatal out-of-body experience.)
The only points on which your description doesn't really match are the boy's body being buried in the house (it isn't, even though he was murdered there and haunts the house) and him being blue-eyed (all the stills I can find that show the boy's eyes seem to show a darker color.)  So I think this is the movie you're looking for.
